# Troubles with MediaPlayers in Xiaomi Mi5 with Miui 8

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm having troubles with mediaplayers in devices with this SO. I handle multiple mediaplayers in loop at the same time and everything seems to work fine until the app suddenly stops with no error in Logcat. It just freeze, it won't shut down nor throw any exception.

I've notice that Logcat shows some kind of error I can't understand and that it does not appear in other devices.

```
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
```

My code:

```
private void createNextMediaPlayer() {
        mNextPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, mResId);
        mNextPlayer.setWakeMode(mContext, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mNextPlayer.setVolume(sonido.getVolumenActual(),sonido.getVolumenActual());
        mCurrentPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(mNextPlayer);
        mCurrentPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
    }

private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mNextPlayer.setVolume(sonido.getVolumenActual(),sonido.getVolumenActual());
            mCurrentPlayer.setVolume(sonido.getVolumenActual(),sonido.getVolumenActual());
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mCurrentPlayer = mNextPlayer;
            createNextMediaPlayer();
}
```

Anyone know what is happening in these devices? Any idea?

Thanks in advance.